# date format on JSON Generator

Tags: javascript, json

I would generate JSON object on [JSON-GENERATOR](https://www.json-generator.com/)

I would that the date have this format : `2017-12-31`

```
[
  '{{repeat(5, 7)}}',
  {
    equityPriceList: [
      {
        date:'{{date(new Date(1970, 0, 1), new Date(),[DD-MM-YYYY])}}',
        identifiant: "4AAM26636",
        lastDayTrading: "50%",
        marketCapitalization: "13,44",
        objectType: "BUSINESS_GROUP",
        priceClosing: "100",
        twelveMHigh: "50",
        twelveMLow: "30"
      }
    ],
    ordering: "1W"
  }
]
```

Actually I get this error

`"date": "<ReferenceError: DD is not defined>"`

I have also tried `datef('YYYY-MM-DD');` and other combinations

Comment: You want to use `dd` instead of `DD`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third parameter should be a String. And the day should be in lowercase.

Just like this:

```
[
  '{{repeat(5, 7)}}',
  {
    equityPriceList: [
      {
        date:'{{date(new Date(1970, 0, 1), new Date(),"dd-MM-YYYY")}}',
        identifiant: "4AAM26636",
        lastDayTrading: "50%",
        marketCapitalization: "13,44",
        objectType: "BUSINESS_GROUP",
        priceClosing: "100",
        twelveMHigh: "50",
        twelveMLow: "30"
      }
    ],
    ordering: "1W"
  }
]
```

Comment: Also if you are expecting to have the format 2017-12-31, then in the date should be like this YYYY-MM-dd

Comment: Yes that was the solution  (`"YYYY-MM-dd"`) but I couldn't add a response to my question right after

Comment: And how to generate month multiple times, NO repeat???